# How to add constraints to v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In terms of [vuejs](http://vuejs.org/):

How to add constraints(limits) to `v-model` properly?
Let's say I want to allow only numbers between `0` and `5`.

```
<input type="number" v-model="model"/>
```

Perhaps I can `watch` input's value. But it's a bit hacky, isn't it?

UPD: Other option is to handle `onChange`, `onKeyUp` and etc and other events: [HTML Text Input allow only Numeric input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469357/930170)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't abuse `watch` for this. use a binding and an event method:

```
<input type="number" v-bind:value="model" @input="handleInput"/>
```

JS:

```
methods: {
  handleInput: function(event) {
    var value = Number(event.target.value)
    if (value > 5) {
      this.model = 5;
    } else if (value < 0 || Number.isNaN(value)) {
      this.model = 0;
    } else {
      this.model = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I use [Vue Validator](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator) for those cases, sample JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gmsa/noy0n18y/):

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <pre>{{$testValidator | json}}</pre>
  <validator name="testValidator">
    <form v-on:submit.prevent="submitForm" novalidate>
      <input type="number" v-model="value" v-validate:value="{min:1, max:10}"/>
      <span class="help-block" v-show="$testValidator.value.max || $testValidator.value.min">Please enter a number between 1 and 10.</span>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </validator>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    value: 1
  },
  methods: {
    submitForm: function() {
      this.$validate(true);
      if (this.$testValidator.valid) {
        // do other stuff here
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: can you provide some example please